# SSH Error: mux_client_hello_exchange: write packet: Broken pipe

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04, ansible

I got this error while running ansible-playbook. But when i retry the error is gone.
It is occurring randomly.

```
sudo ansible-playbook /home/ubuntu/ansible_deployment/copy_nginx_conf.yml --extra-vars branch=submissions --private-key /home/ubuntu/ansible_deployment/key.pem

PLAY [stg-app] **************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
 fatal: [52.10.142.55] => SSH Error: mux_client_hello_exchange: write packet: Broken pipe
 It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.

 TASK: [file path=/opt/nginx/conf/sites-enabled/ state=directory mode=0755] **** 
 FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting


 PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
       to retry, use: --limit @/var/lib/jenkins/copy_nginx_conf.retry

52.10.142.55               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Comment: You need to give more information! The broken pipe error often means that the SSH session died, which could be for many reasons. Two places to look for clues. One: SSH in yourself as the user Ansible is connecting as, with `ssh -vvvv`. Two: look in the server's logs for clues - /var/log/secure and /var/log/messages are good starting points.

Comment: I had a problem with similar symptoms and it apparently was this bug in Ansible (or a bug in SSH client impacting Ansible): https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16731
Your problem may be different, because it occurs during the fact gathering and not in any long running operations.